# .asp can't filter data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnerd.png)  Considering the following code:

```
<form name="queryForm" onsubmit="sortData('<%= sortBy %>'); return false;">
<table class="searchtable ">
   <tr><td class="label">Territory ID </td><td><input type="text" name="filterCustomer_TerritoryID" value="<% filterCustomer_TerritoryID %>"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" onclick="sortData('<%= sortBy %>'); return false;" value="Search"/>
<br/><br/>
</form>
```

When I open it in explorer, the result in `.searchtable` is:

```
<% filterCustomer_TerritoryID %>
```

I want to type in filter value in `.searchtable`. Any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Comment: If your purpose is to make a table searchable there are a couple of good jquery plugins, such as datatables.net with all those features built in

Comment: I thought value="<% filterCustomer_TerritoryID %>"  was wrong, I wanted to use Customer.TerritoryID as filter from database. it seemed like in my code, "filterCustomer_TerritoryID" is text rather than a parameter.

Comment: Your table only has one row?

Comment: Thank you. My table has many rows.

Comment: So why you don't use an asp:repeater instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to browser, because it is server side code that must change to html.You must change this:

```
value="<% filterCustomer_TerritoryID %>"
```

to this:

```
value="<%= filterCustomer_TerritoryID %>"
```

And filterCustomer_TerritoryID must be a protected or public field.

[image: I tested your code and that image was the result.]

Comment: Sorry, if I change to value="<%=filterCustomer_TerritoryID%>" , then the result would be like image in question, only the text in search field change to <%=filterCustomer_TerritoryID%>.  I updated my question, I attached the result image when I run my .asp file. Thanks

Comment: I tested your code exactly and the image is result of that. If the sortBy is a method you must change to this: sortBy()

Comment: Please check your code behind if your fields are protected or public and check tags before form if you have a bad formed tag.

Comment: Did you use my code with value="<%=filterCustomer_TerritoryID>" to get your result like your image? That the search field "the value" showed up?

Comment: Thank you Farzin, I'm going to check the filed is protected or not first.

Comment: Yes i used value="<%=filterCustomer_TerritoryID>".

Comment: Thank you. Then the reason should be the column is private that I can't use it directly. I am going to check other parts of my code as well. thanks again,